# How can I remove Google drive from my PC without deleting any cloud stored file?

Tags: ssd, storage, google-drive, cloud-storage

I'm currently in the process of upgrading my 500GB SSD to a 2TB one so I can have more storage to use Google drive files on it. I'm wondering if there's a way to delete all the Google drive files from my PC without affecting the actual cloud stored files.

Do I just turn sync off and uninstall Google drive?

Comment: Just uninstalling Google Drive (or whatever it’s currently called) should be enough, once uninstalled, you can delete or move your files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Google Help article
[Back up & sync files with Google Drive](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2374987?hl=en&ref_topic=6069785):

> **Choose what to sync from Google Drive**
>
> You can sync files and folders in Google Drive to your computer for
> offline use.
>
> 1. On your computer, click Backup and Sync Backup and Sync [image]
> 2. Click More [image: More] and then Preferences
> 3. At the left, click Google Drive
> 4. Click *Sync My Drive to this computer*
> 5. Choose if you want to:
>
>    - Sync everything in My Drive
>    - Sync only these folders
> 6. Click OK.

When you get to step 5 above, select the option to "Sync only these folders" if it isn't already set. You then get to check or un-check which folders in your local Google Drive folder you want to sync. Once done, click OK and Google Backup and Sync immediately applies the changes to your local computer without deleting any of your files in the cloud.
(But I would recommend taking a backup in case of a wrong manipulation.)

Comment: Thanks! I'll try that.